# How can I use htaccess redirect rules?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I want to redirect request to sample.php if pattern was like below

sample.com/vacation

I tried this code but not work correctly, redirect all request contain vacation such as sample.com/anything/vacation

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /vacation
RewriteRule ^ /sample.php [L,R]
```

how can I achieve that ?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your htacces file, could you please do share if you got any error also when you tried these rules?

Comment: there is no error happening when i use this rule
but i want to redirect request by this pattern only :

sample.com/vacation

not somthing like that :

ample.com/anything/vacation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^vacation/?$ sample.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: thank you so much, this code resolve my issue